How can I explicitly set the height in shiny's renderCachedPlot?
I have a Shiny app that compares three plots to each other based on user input. It's getting a bit slow, so I'm trying to implement renderCachedPlot so that at least the first one, which only changes based on one user input (the other two require multiple) is loaded faster. It works, except that the height no longer takes up the height I want it to, even when I set sizes.
Initially I had something like this, only changing renderPlot to renderCachedPlot
output$a <- renderCachedPlot({
ggplot(data = data, aes(x,y)+geom_col), 
height = 550})

sizePolicy didn't work either, even when I set the height to an absurd size and fiddled with growth ratio and width as well, and got outputs that were illegible.
Editing the CSS/HTML as below kind of works, but stretches out the plot in a way that regular renderPlot doesn't:
.shiny-scalable{
  min-height: 550px;
}


My best guess is this has something to do with scaling the width and height in a way that doesn't affect the aspect ratio (at least too much), but is a straightforward solution? The plots using renderPlot look fine on different screen sizes, and I fear this won't.
Example code:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- page_sidebar(
    # useShinyjs(),
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "morph"),
    sidebar = sidebar(
        sliderInput("val", "Value", 
                    min = 0, max = 100, 
                    value = 50,
                    width = "100%"),
    ), #endsidebar
    layout_column_wrap(
        max_height = 200,
        card(
            card_header("Before"),
            id = "beforeplot",
            plotOutput("before")
        ),
        card(
            card_header("After"),
            id = "afterplot",
            plotOutput("after")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
output$before <- renderPlot({
    df.a <- data.frame(x = c("Pink", "Teal"), 
                       y = c(20, 80))
    
    df.a |> ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = x))+
        geom_col()
})
output$after <- renderCachedPlot({
    b <- input$val
    df.b <- data.frame(x = c("Pink", "Teal"), 
                       y = c(b, 100-b))
    df.b |> ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = x))+
        geom_col()
}, 
cacheKeyExpr = input$val, 
sizePolicy = sizeGrowthRatio(height = 2500)
)
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



What you need is unclear. Setting the max_height argument in layout_column_wrap adjusts the plot size accordingly, for both type of plot.
